# Text is always bold for some reason

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out how to make h2 used for the text, "Tennis in Toronto" at look like the h2 used for the text, "Summer Camp" (in the main content area) at. I think that there is a font-weight: bold; that is causing the problem, but I can't find it at all in any of the css files. Here's the CSS for "Tennis in Toronto".

```
#wrap h2.title a, #wrap h2.title {
font-family: "Open Sans", arial, serif !important;
letter-spacing: .02em;
color: #999999;
font-size: 140%;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<h2 class="title">
<a href="./viewforum.php?f=3">Tennis in Toronto</a>
</h2>
```

Can someone please help me out? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What browser and version are you seeing this in? Using Firefox 31 they look the same to me.

Comment: If you're using the Google Fonts API, the font-weight for Open Sans regular is 400, 700 is bold. `font-weight:400;` should work, provided you've included that weight in your `import` i.e. `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300);`

Comment: I used html to import the font: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h2` element with the text "Summer Camps" has a class named `.pagetitle`, which sets the font weight to 300.

If you want to use this style on all your `h2` elements, then use:

```
h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

But it's probably a better idea to style just the `.title` class:

```
.title {
     font-weight: 300;
}
```

Also, make sure you've included this style in your Google Fonts collection.

Answer (score 1):

try setting it to normal weight. headers are bold by default

> h2{  font-weight:normal; }

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS and the elements class:

Notice that the bold title "Tennis in Toronto" has the class `title`. While "Summer Camp" has the class `pagetitle`. So if you want "Tennis in Toronto" to look like "Summer Camp" then change it's class from `title` to `pagetitle`.

**Update**

To un-bold your item like you said, remove `font-weight: bold` in it's CSS. Specifically from the item `#wrap a.forumtitle, #wrap a.topictitle{ ... }`. Also note that "Summer Camp" is an `<h2>` element while "Tennis in Toronto" is not. So be sure to take into consideration the CSS of `<h2>` elements on the page.

Comment: They have two different css files. "Summer Camp" is on the main website built in Wordpress. "Tennis in Toronto" is text in the forum built using PHPBB.

Comment: That's fine. You can still find the CSS and copy it to yours. Go to this link and search `pagetitle` and you will find it: http://www.ilovetennis.ca/wp-content/themes/I-L-T-Theme/style.css

Answer (score -3):

I am not 100% sure about this but I think h2 is automatically bold just like < a > is automatically underlined. try this in the style sheet:

```
h2.title{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```